# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar las etiquetas de valor en R?

Tags: r, shiny

Estoy haciendo un *dashboard* con `Shiny (R)`. Mi objetivo es que en el *dashboard* se vea la base de datos que está en `STATA`.

Para abrir la base utilizo `haven` y hasta ahí todo bien. El problema viene cuando intento adherir la base al *dashboard*, pues si bien me abre, no visualiza los datos en el *dashboard*, por lo que me arroja el siguiente error:

> DataTables warning: tabla
> id=DataTables_Table_()-Error:dim<-haven_labelled()not supported.

Según entiendo el problema es que `haven` no acepta las etiquetas. Entonces lo que yo necesito es eliminar las etiquetas de valor.

En concreto mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo eliminar las etiquetas de valor en `R` sin tener que utilizar `SPSS` o `STATA`?

Comment: ¿Probaste con `as.numeric` o `haven::as_factor()`? Ambas coercionan un obejto de la clase `haven_labelled` a numérico o factor respectivamente.

Comment: Sí, ya me resultó. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @mpaladino deberías poner eso como respuesta

Comment: Gracias por la sugenrencia @AlvaroMontoro, ya lo hice. Pensé que no era apropiado al no dar una solución específica, pero a sugerencia de eminencia...

Answer (score 1):

¿Probaste con `as.numeric()` o `haven::as_factor()`? Ambas coercionan un objeto de la clase `haven_labelled` a `numeric` o `factor` respectivamente.